# Why is shell treating a part of the output of $(<file) as a command?

Tags: shell, output, command-substitution

I saw this line while reading [a blog on IFS](http://asystemengineersnotebook.blogspot.in/2016/12/getting-to-know-ifs-internal-field.html) that is :

```
for i in $(<test.txt)
```

And thought that `$(<test.txt)` prints the file contents to STDOUT. I maybe wrong in this, but out of curiosity I tried to do it on shell. So picked up a random file named `array` having random data and

First did a `cat array` that gave me this :

```
amit@C0deDaedalus:~/test$ 
amit@C0deDaedalus:~/test$ cat array
1)      Ottawa  Canada          345644
2)      Kabul   Afghanistan     667345
3)      Paris   France          214423
4)      Moscow  Russia          128793
5)      Delhi   India           142894
```

And then did `$(<array)` that gave me this :

```
amit@C0deDaedalus:~/test$ $(<array)
1)      Ottawa  Ca: command not found
```

I only know that `<` is used for input redirection but not getting exactly what is being interpreted by shell as a command here.

Can anyone explain the concept behind this weird output in shell ?

Update :-

On running `set -x` it gives this :

```
amit@C0deDaedalus:~/test$ $(<array)
+ '1)' Ottawa Canada 345644 '2)' Kabul Afghanistan 667345 '3)' Paris France 214423 '4)' Moscow Russia 128793 '5)' Delhi India 142894
+ '[' -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ']'
+ /usr/lib/command-not-found -- '1)'
1): command not found
+ return 127
amit@C0deDaedalus:~/test$
```

Comment: It should have directly thrown that error, but why after printing this much part `1)      Ottawa  Ca` ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce that with 4.4.19. I get the error only for `1)`. My bash does not truncate long not found names either. Execute `set -x` and run `$(<array)` again. Maybe the debug output is helpful.

Comment: I am running these commands on `4.4.0-121-generic`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `$(command)` syntax executes `command` in a subshell environment and replaces itself with the standard output of `command`. And, [as Bash Manual says](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html), `$(< file)` is just a faster equivalent of `$(cat file)` (that's not a POSIX feature, though).

So when you run `$(<array)`, Bash performs that substitution, then it uses the first field as the command's name and the rest of the fields as command's arguments:

```
$ $(<array)
1): command not found
```

I don't have any `1)` command/function, so it prints an error message.

But in your specific scenario, you are getting a different error message probably because you modified the IFS variable:

```
$ IFS=n; $(<array)
1)      Ottawa  Ca: command not found
```

---

#### Edit 1

My guess is that your `IFS` was somehow modified, so that's why your shell tried to execute `1)      Ottawa  Ca` instead of `1)`. After all, you were reading an `IFS`-related article. I wouldn't be surprised if your `IFS` ended up with a weird value.

The `IFS` variable controls what is known as *word splitting* or *field splitting*. It basically defines how the data will be parsed by the shell in an expansion context (or by other commands like `read`).

[Bash manual explains this topic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html):

> #### 3.5.7 Word Splitting
>
> The shell scans the results of parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion that did not occur within double quotes for word splitting.
>
> The shell treats each character of `$IFS` as a delimiter, and splits the results of the other expansions into words using these characters as field terminators. If `IFS` is unset, or its value is exactly `<space><tab><newline>`, the default, then sequences of `<space>`, `<tab>`, and `<newline>` at the beginning and end of the results of the previous expansions are ignored, and any sequence of `IFS` characters not at the beginning or end serves to delimit words. If `IFS` has a value other than the default, then sequences of the whitespace characters `space`, `tab`, and `newline` are ignored at the beginning and end of the word, as long as the whitespace character is in the value of `IFS` (an `IFS` whitespace character). Any character in `IFS` that is not `IFS` whitespace, along with any adjacent `IFS` whitespace characters, delimits a field. A sequence of `IFS` whitespace characters is also treated as a delimiter. If the value of `IFS` is null, no word splitting occurs.
>
> Explicit null arguments (`""` or `''`) are retained and passed to commands as empty strings. Unquoted implicit null arguments, resulting from the expansion of parameters that have no values, are removed. If a parameter with no value is expanded within double quotes, a null argument results and is retained and passed to a command as an empty string. When a quoted null argument appears as part of a word whose expansion is non-null, the null argument is removed. That is, the word `-d''` becomes `-d` after word splitting and null argument removal.
>
> Note that if no expansion occurs, no splitting is performed.

Here are some examples about `IFS` and command substitution usage:

**Example 1:**

```
$ IFS=$' \t\n'; var='hello     world'; printf '[%s]\n' ${var}
[hello]
[world]

$ IFS=$' \t\n'; var='hello     world'; printf '[%s]\n' "${var}"
[hello     world]
```

In both cases, `IFS` is `<space><tab><newline>` (the default value), `var` is `hello     world` and there's a `printf` statement. But note that in the first case word splitting is performed, while in the second case it is not (because double-quotes inhibit that behavior). **Word splitting occurs in non-quoted expansions.**

**Example 2:**

```
$ IFS='x'; var='fooxbar'; printf '[%s]\n' ${var}
[foo]
[bar]

$ IFS='2'; (exit 123); printf '[%s]\n' ${?}
[1]
[3]
```

Neither `${var}` nor `${?}` contain any whitespace character, so one may think that word splitting wouldn't be an issue in such cases. But that's not true because `IFS` can be abused. **`IFS` can hold virtually any value and it's easy to abuse.**

**Example 3:**

```
$ $(echo uname)
Linux

$ $(xxd -p -r <<< 64617465202d75)
Sat Apr 28 12:46:49 UTC 2018

$ var='echo foo; echo bar'; eval "$(echo "${var}")"
foo
bar
```

This has nothing to do with word splitting, but note how we can use some dirty tricks to inject code.

**Related questions:**

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/243481)
- [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/243481)

Comment: Could you please explain the `IFS` variable modify part.

Comment: @C0deDaedalus Just edited the answer.

Comment: You are very true. It was a messed up `$IFS` issue. Anyways thanks for your answer.

Comment: Those statements at end of examples speak much bold then they are. Also can you explain a little about 2nd abuse in the 3rd example. I didn't get it.

Comment: @C0deDaedalus `xxd` is a tool that converts text to hexadecimal and vice versa. `64617465202d75` is the hex representation of `date -u`. So `$(xxd -p -r <<< 64617465202d75)` is just an obscure and obfuscated way to execute `date -u`. Imagine doing that with something like `rm -rf /` instead. Such non-intelligible command would be pretty dangerous for an inexperienced user lead by his/her curiosity.

Comment: I want to upvote this several times.